# Back up and restore Bejeweled 3 after HDD format on Windows 7 PC

Tags: bejeweled-3

I'm going to format my Windows 7 x64 PC and I will make a fresh installation of Bejeweled 3. The problem is, I've made a big progress in the game and I don't want to lose the current state of the game (some levels are available only after a certain progress in the game).

What should I do to protect my state in the game? Are just backing up `C:\Program Files (x86)\PopCap Games\Bejeweled 3` folder and restoring it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gladly that will only backup your game not all your stats...

You have to go to the c:\Users\&YourUserName&\AppData\Local\PopCap Games\Bejeweled3\Users

Note to do this you need to unhide the hidden files and folders...

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your version it can be in:

- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\**PopCap Games**\Bejeweled3\Users
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\**Steam**\Bejeweled3\Users
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\**GameHouse**\Bejeweled3\users
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\**iWin**\Bejeweled3\users
- etc...

...where %USERPROFILE% is C:\Users\*Your username here*\

The exact location unfortunately depends on what version of the game you are playing. Yes, copy pasting this folder should be enough to transfer your profile completely.

Answer (score 2):

For my copy of the game its in...

`c:\Users\**YourUserName**\AppData\Local\iWin\Bejeweled3\Users`

But if there are multiple publishers selling the game then you might find it at a different path.

Answer (score 1):

Save games can be located in the following location `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\GameHouse\Bejeweled3\users`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me when moving the Steam version from Windows XP to Windows 7:

- Back up at least your C:\Program Files\steam\steamapps\common\Bejeweled 3\users
- Play Steam's Bejeweled 3 once on Windows 7 so it will create the C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Steam\Bejeweled3\users directory (you could create it yourself but where's the fun in that.)
- Copy the contents from C:\Program Files\steam\steamapps\common\Bejeweled 3\users to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Steam\Bejeweled3\users and replace everything (aw. you just lost that quick game you played.)
- Start Bejeweled 3 and check your Records -> Badges to verify all your previous achievements are there. (Yes. I still have my Annihilator & Superstar)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool to make this process easier you can find it here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bejeweled3savegamemanager/